# Please mention a few music making softwares for ubuntu

Tags: music

We know that there are many a software for windows which help aid the musician or the music producers , are there any such equivalents in the ubuntu world if yes please share

Comment: [Ubuntu Studio](https://ubuntustudio.org/) is a Ubuntu derivative with allot of multi media tools per-installed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following are few that you might like to give it a try:
(I have given links for each software for you to read all features in detail)

1. **JACK:** *Jack Audio Connection Kit* is probably the most celebrated tool as far as music production on Linux is concerned. It's ability to integrate with various other applications makes it favourite candidate. One of the distinct feature is that it provides cross-platform API that enables not only device sharing but also inter-application audio routing. It also shows a very easy learning curve.[JACK](http://jackaudio.org/)
2. **Ardour:** It is a Digital Audio Workstation (DAW), suitable for recording, mixing and mastering. It can be easily integrated with all *JACK* applications. 
   [Ardour](http://ardour.org/)
3. **Linux Multimedia Studio:**  Also know as **LMMS**, it provides you enough features to get your work done and that too beautifully. It is compatible with MIDI keyboard and hence allows import of MIDI and FruityLoops(FLP) files. 
   [LMMS](https://lmms.io/)
4. **Rosegarden:** This one is for those who like to compose.[Rosegarden](http://www.rosegardenmusic.com/)
5. **Audacity:** Need not mention features for this one. The one of the most famous audio editing software is also available for Ubuntu.[Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/)

There are many more available but I have mentioned the most famous and with most features.

Additionally you can also try **Ubuntu Studio** is which a flavour of Ubuntu solely customized for *Multimedia purpose*. It comes with many of above mentioned music/audio softwares pre-installed. Do have a look at it's benefits here: [Ubuntu Studio](https://ubuntustudio.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the most ambitious one is the multi-platform paid proprietary DAW called [Bitwig Studio](http://bitwig.com/), which is quite similar to popular Ableton (in fact, it's built by some Ableton developers). You can also try a more traditional and totally free and open source DAW [Ardour](http://ardour.org/) (well, you have the "pay what you want" price for downloading the binaries, but you can download the sources for free and compile them). And, of course, there is [LMMS](https://lmms.io/) (Linux Multimedia Studio), which is also free and open source. See [this list](http://wiki.linuxaudio.org/apps/daw_apps) for more information.

A popular (and cheap) Windows DAW [Reaper](http://www.reaper.fm/) doesn't have a Linux version, but is developed with Wine compatibility in mind, so it runs fine.

You can also pay attention to [Ubuntu Studio](https://ubuntustudio.org/tour/audio/). While there is nothing you can't install in your regular Ubuntu, Ubuntu Studio offers you a lot of things just out of the box.